# Angular 4 - ngfor with ngif error

Tags: angular

I'm developing anuglar 4 project, where the data is fetched in the component
Loop through it in the select html, but i want to mark specific option as selected according to it's name

Code

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
    <option  *ngFor="let field of fields" *ngIf="field.name == 'Select me'; then selected='true'">{{field.name}}</option>
</select>
```

but it's not working when using ngif with ngfor

Error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *
```

Comment: instaed of *ngIf you can use [selected]="field.name==='Select me'" property for selecting the option

Comment: @JayDeeEss has the right idea. This really, really isn't what `ngIf` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `ngIf` you can use [selected]="field.name==='Select me'" property for selecting the option

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
        <option  *ngFor="let field of fields" [selected]="field.name==='Select me'">{{field.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You should return `null` if you don't want the attribute to show up. I think this way, every option will have the selected attribute.

Comment: you can definitely do that but this would do too as for all other that wont match it will return false and it won't be selected anyways!